# How Can I wait asyncio.Future from another thread and another loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

Hello I would like to know. How Can I wait asyncio.Future from another thread and another loop? For example. I have a code that wait result from coroutine

```
 if isinstance(target, Future):
            await target
            result = target
```

but the problem is that this code is running from another thread. And I get a exception

> got Future  attached to a different loop

Question: How Can I wait asyncio.Future from another thread?

P.S. I understand that I must use one Loop but architecture of my solution required to start a separate thread and wait for completion asyncio.Future

Comment: I understand that you sometimes need two threads, but why do you need two separate **loops**? If you start a separate thread, you can still submit stuff to the original loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How Can I wait asyncio.Future from another thread and another loop?

You're not supposed to. Even if you need another thread, you can always submit work to an existing single event loop using [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

But if you really *really* need this, you can do it like this (untested), although I would strongly advise against it. This will temporarily work around serious architectural issues, which *will* come back to haunt you.

```
if isinstance(target, Future):
    my_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    if target.get_loop() is my_loop:
        result = await target
    else:
        target_loop = target.get_loop()
        my_target = my_loop.create_future()
        def wait_target():
            try:
                result = await target
            except Exception as e:
                my_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(my_target.set_exception, e)
            else:
                my_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(my_target.set_result, result)
        target_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(wait_target)
        result = await my_target
```

Comment: Indeed, this has a tendency to haunt you. I had an API with a loop spawned in each thread, and I had bugs associated with something similar to this. The best alternative was to use an event-loop based API to mitigate the issue - just if anyone wanted to know just how much this haunts.